# willTransitionToTraitCollection not called on first change when UISplitViewController preferredDisplayMode is Overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a UISplitViewController and in my detail view, I am trying to use `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` to change the visibility of a couple views when the vertical size class changes to Compact.

On only the iPhone (not iPhone Plus or iPad) If I change the `preferredDisplayMode` to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay`, `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` is not called the first time the device is rotated, but `willTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` is. If I set `preferredDisplayMode` to anything else it works just fine. If you rotate the device prior to selecting an item in the Master list, it works just fine. It is ONLY on the first rotation from portrait to landscape.

This is easily reproduced using the Master-Detail template:

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    // ******** Add this ********
    [splitViewController setPreferredDisplayMode:UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
    splitViewController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
```

In `DetailViewController`, add the `viewWillTransitionToTraitCollection` and `viewWillTransitionToSize` implementations and set breakpoints:

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

You will see that `willTransitionToSize:` is always called, but `willTransitionToTraitCollection:` is not called for the first transition.

Does anyone know why this is? I feel like this is a bug, but I wanted to see if anyone has an explanation before I send a bug report into Apple's bug reporter black hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with "this is a bug".

I've submitted a bug report to Apple and have created a radar for it: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5015544713445376

Answer (score -1):

setPreferredDisplayMode makes all the views load, so you should call it last.

Comment: That's not true. iPhone has compact width & height in landscape only, but it has compact width & regular height in portrait, so willTransitionToTraitCollection should be called on every device rotation. Besides, if that were the case, this would never be called (as on iPad), but it IS called on every device rotation AFTER the first one, and this only happens in the situation I described originally.

Comment: @JordanBondo can you take a look at my updated answer